# How to write a php service that uploads new sqlite data from android to mysql at intervals

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I know this is a common question already but i cannot seem to find an answer that addresses my issue.I already have a php script that uploads data to from SQLite android to mySQL as JSON.That works just fine.What i'm having trouble with is the following:

1. I need to write a service(i'm using php)that checks SQLite at regular intervals,say 30 min and uploads any new data not already present in MySQL.

So i haven't found anything on how to write that kind of script(with the time intervals) using php.I would really appreciate some help or links to any such tutorials.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my question.I did not know about the android sync adapter framework.It Synchronizes data between an Android device and web servers ..and

> can make your application significantly more useful and compelling for your users.

So for my app,i needed to sync data from sqlite to a mysql server periodically and this does just that!I got this from the android developer's site,incase anyone else needs more information i future (http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)!